# UIBarButtonItem tintColor iOS4

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios4

I am using following code to create a UIBarButtonItem:

```
UIBarButtonItem* searchBarButton = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"search_picto"] style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(actionSearch:)] autorelease];
searchBarButton.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.27 green:0.60 blue:0.20 alpha:1.00];
```

I add this and another button to a UIToolbar, not sure if that's relevant.
This works fine and gives me the look I intended:

[image: screenshot of UIButtonBarItem]

The problem is that with iOS 4 (which I have to support) I can't set the tintColor. Unrecognized Selector. How can I create such a button for iOS 4? I need to be able to set the tintColor and have UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered.

Thanks for your help.

---

I got it to work like this:

```
UISegmentedControl* searchButton = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"", nil]];
[searchButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"search_picto"] forSegmentAtIndex:0];
searchButton.momentary = YES;
searchButton.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
searchButton.tintColor = [DELEGATE.config getColor:IFXShopConfigScopeShop name:@"navigationTint"];
[searchButton addTarget:self action:@selector(actionSearch:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

You have to initialize it with one empty NSString, otherwise you can't set an image. Also the addTarget has to use `UIControlEventValueChanged`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tintColor` was added in iOS5, for iOS4 [here](http://charles.lescampeurs.org/2011/02/10/tint-color-uibutton-and-uibarbuttonitem) you have a solution

Comment: I looked at this yesterday, seems it's the right way after all.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an `UIButton` and either draw the button to look like this by yourself or set a background image with this and initialize the `UIBarButtonItem` with a custom view (your `UIButton`).

P.S. From the release of iOS6 you can't compile to armv6 anymore and the lowest version you can support is 4.3, which according to me isn't worth it...